# Deleting a record in a ClientDatSet wont remove it in my XML file

Tags: delphi

Im writing a DB program where i have a DBGrid and Navagator hooked up to a DataSource witch is hooked up to a ClientDataSet. This saves to an XML file. When I use the navigator to delete a record it is removed from the DBGrid (also when i restart app), however it is still in the XML file. I'd like to keep things clean, so is there a way to remove a record from the XML file just by using the components i have now?

```
procedure TForm1.serverExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
sLoginName, sPassword: string;
LoginExist: Boolean;
NewLogin: TStringList;
begin
  if AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn = 'NewAccount' then
    lbLog.Items.Add('New account request form: '  + aContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP);
    sLoginName := aContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
    sPassword := aContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
    lbLog.Items.Add('With Login Name: ' + sLoginName);

    LoginExist := False;
    ClientDataSet1.DisableControls;
    try
      ClientDataSet1.First;
      while not ClientDataSet1.Eof do
      begin
        if ClientDataSet1.Fields[0].Value = sLoginName then
        begin
          LoginExist := True;
          Break;
        end;
        ClientDataSet1.Next;
      end;
    finally
      ClientDataSet1.EnableControls;
    end;
  if LoginExist = false then
  begin
    NewLogin := TStringList.Create;
    NewLogin.Add(sLoginName);
    NewLogin.Add(sPassword);
    lbLog.Items.Add('Name accepted');
    lbLog.Items.Add('---------------');
    ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([NewLogin[0], NewLogin[1]]);
    FreeAndNil(NewLogin);
    lbLog.Items.Add('');
  end
  else
    lbLog.Items.Add('Login name allready exists');
    lbLog.Items.Add('---------------');
```

Comment: See [`MergeChangeLog`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Merging_Changes_into_Data).

Comment: yeas Ive disabled changelog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TClientDataset` component does not save its records to the external file automatically. You have to call `TClientDataset.SaveToFile` method each time you want to sync the file with the in-memory records.

If you want to keep both file and records (in the `TClientDataset`s´s vernacle, it´s named as `Data`) in perfect sync all the time, add handlers to `AfterDelete` and `AfterPost` events and save the dataset content by calling such a method.

Also in your code, I could see that you run a loop to find a record for the a certain login. There is a method named `Locate` that I consider useful in this situation, so my suggestion is to refactor you code to use it.

I advise you to take some time to read the component´s help, it´s a very good way to better learn how to use it.

**UPDATE:**

Regarding the `TClientDataset.FileName`, property, the help says:

*"Changes are not merged into the data when it is saved to the file. This allows an application that employs the "briefcase" model to set FileName without losing updates that are destined for a database server. Single-tiered applications should explicitly merge changes before closing the dataset and saving the data to disk."*

I guess this explains why the deleted records are still present in the saved file.

Comment: I have set the filename property of the clientdataset. Stuff is being saved to that file. I'm gonna look in to the rest of you advice thank you

Comment: awsome. Gonna not use the filename property of the cds and switch over to savetofile. Thank you verry much